# Running out of time in attacks

Tags: clash-of-clans

Recently I've attacked several war bases where my barbarians destroy all the defence but then the time runs out before I can get any stars. Is there any general advice to solve this? I tried lowering the number of giants and getting more wizards but this doesn't seem to help. Another thought is trying to take care of the protecting troops from the clan faster, for example deploying more wizards faster after the troops have been loured out.

I'm TH level 7. I usually use 1 or 2 healing spells and rage. I usually have 1 healer (sometimes 2).

Comment: Can you tell us your army/spell compositions? | You could try adding some hog riders... (If you have them)

Comment: More information is required. Generally, you want to make sure all defenses are down as soon as possible since this enables you to keep more troops alive for cleanup. If you are at town hall 7 or 8, using all dragons is usually the best attack you can use to 3 star bases of equal level within the time limit (you hardly need to lure cc troops with all dragon attacks).

Comment: Start your attack right when the 3-2-1 countdown starts, then you will get an extra 3 seconds! :)

Answer (score 5):

Battle time becomes a serious concern as you approach the top tiers of TH7.  The giant/healer strategy starts to become too slow against many well-designed bases.

It's important to find out where you're spending your time.  You can watch the replays and count seconds to get a pretty accurate picture of what's happening.

Probably the most critical parts are drawing out the clan castle troops and dealing with walls.  Even a big pack of Giants still takes time to break through walls, and when many walls stand between you and your goal, things can slow down significantly.

The clan castle is important to draw out no matter what troops you're using, but you can be attacking another part of the base at the same time, if you're confident in your clan castle drawing skills.  This sort of divided focus can be hard to manage, so practice it against matchmaking bases outside of war until you get the hang of it.

As some have said, air attacks can be faster, as air units bypass walls.  This gets expensive, though, and it requires training to understand the best way to deploy air troops.  All dragon attacks are usually so costly that you won't profit in terms of elixir from wars.  However, if you're late TH7, you might not care about elixir, and you might just be in wars for the DE/gold for walls.  If that's the case, then by all means blow elixir on dragons.  A mix of dragons and balloons can be cheaper, and if you deploy them strategically it's possible to 3* a lot of different TH7 bases this way.

Also, you can bring along wall breakers to speed up the wall destruction process for your ground troops.  This becomes somewhat difficult against bases with deep walls, as the breakers don't have much HP, take decent troop space, and are useless against things that aren't walls.  If you've got a very "honeycomb" base you're up against, though, they can be devastating if used properly.

So tl;dr:

1. Watch your replays and figure out where that time is going
2. Learn to manage clan castle troops quickly
3. Try different strategies - more air or wall breakers, for instance
4. Practice against similar bases outside of war so that your strategy is honed and you can consistently deploy it properly

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change your strategy. Some types of attacks take longer, like yours. Use another battle strategy. A popular one at TH 7 is an all dragon attack. If you haven't unlocked dragons, you can upgrade your barracks.

Comment: As far as easy answers are concerned, this one fits the bill. If the only thing you're interested in is scoring stars in war, attacking an enemy TH7 base as a TH7 base yourself with 10 level 2 dragons, 1 level 3 dragon (donated) and 3 lightning spells to destroy an air defense tower prior to the attack will score 3 stars the vast majority of the time, regardless of layout.